# Windows 10 Desktop - Desktop folder is displayed on desktop, not a shortcut, how to get rid of it?

Tags: windows, windows-10

This is more annoying than anything, having an icon I cannot delete. This folder is pointing to my user desktop folder on the C drive but it is not a shortcut. If I delete it, then it deletes my desktop. I cant seem to find a solution to the problem. Anyone have any ideas how to get rid of this?

-Cannot delete
-Cannot move to another location

[image: Desktop folder on Windows 10 desktop]

Comment: What do you see if you run `attrib C:\users\your-user\Desktop\*.*` from an elevated Command Prompt?

Comment: A  SH                C:\users\bowmab\Desktop\desktop.ini

Comment: What about same command, but the path of `C:\Users\Public\Public Desktop`?

Comment: It shows the same output